# How to remove/change print document margin in printTask?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, winjs, windows-8.1

I wonder how I can achieve a borderless print.

At the moment my output looks like this:

[image: border I'm referring to is marked red]

I'd like to have the image start at the very top left corner. Is this possible? I already tried to set a negative margin to my print-style box, but the image will get cut then.

I know that maybe not all printers are capable of printing the area of the border, but in my use-case the picture will be white in these areas. (The mountain-image is just for demo purposes)

Can I specify the document border somehow via printTask?

See my current setup:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pdf-render-output"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body > #pdf-render-output {
    display: none;
}

@media print {

    body > * {
       display:none;
       max-width: 100%;
    }

    html {
       max-width: 100%;
       border-top: 0;
    }

    body > #pdf-render-output {
        display: block;
        border: none;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0; /* I tried to set negative margin/padding eg. here */
        padding: 0;
    }

}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#pdf-render-output').append("<img src="..." style=\"width: 100%\" />");
```

I played around with all possible margins/paddings and stuff, but the image will get cut and the white border stays 'over' it.

I hope that there might be a printTask-option I missed browsing the msdn?

**Update:**
I tried to set all margin/padding/border values with !important. No change.
Here is a screenshot from the simulator, displaying only the print-css-style:
[image]

I got to the point thinking it's an issue with the printTask itself. Are there any options regarding to this problem?

Comment: Do you have any code associated with this ? So please post it where you assign margin,or place your picture ?

Comment: `var img = $('<img  />');
img.css({'position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:red'});
$('#pdf-render-output').append(img);
` 


 please try with this..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly the border stays as before. Absolute positioning is not the key here I think. Might it be an issue with <body> padding/margin? (I already tried setting it to 0, but no change).
Or if you think about the common print-possibilities from ordinary programs: There you can sometimes specify the border-width. Maybe there is something similiar somewhere for WinJS?

Comment: I suggest you to ,set  `body`,`html` and the other `elements`  to `margin:0!important` and same for boder-width,padding use `!important` and then try it, may be it is dynamically assign.And See your `DOM`while it's debugging,there you can find the reason.

Comment: @AshishMishra tried it and had no luck :/ See results above.

Comment: ya, May be its by default , their is `no margin` but its a `default style`,But the `right bar` is a `page` that is created by you then its possible to change,i Don't know why its happening in your case..if a Bar `Send To OneNote 2013` is created by you then you may change this otherwise not!

Comment: Unfortunately the bar and the whole print-handling is created and conducted by the system in W8. That's why I hoped there might be some options for the printTask.

Comment: So,Its a `Print Preview` !! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the margin values of DocumentSource is set to 0, gaps will decrease very much. However, compared with PrintTask by C#+XAML, a top margin(Probably header/footer area) is made a little.

```
var printTask = printEvent.request.createPrintTask("Print Sample", function (args) {
    var src = MSApp.getHtmlPrintDocumentSource(document);
    src.rightMargin = 0;
    src.leftMargin = 0;
    src.topMargin = 0;
    src.bottomMargin = 0;
    src.shrinkToFit = false;
    args.setSource(src);
}
```

In my environment, when this CSS was used, it has removed the margin without the necessity for src.rightMargin, etc.

```
@page {
    margin:0cm;
}
```

Comment: `@page` did the trick! Thank you very much. This should be documented somewhere... (Or did I just miss it?)

Comment: I have the same problem and it does not work for me. Its only reduce right margin a bit (not whole), but top margin is the same. I did not try with @page css property, do not how to put it on my document, because I create doc manually.

Comment: the @page did the trick for me too. And how malte said: it isnt documented anywhere, but it should be

Comment: if I create my document fragment like this:
var container = document.createElement("div");
        container.innerHTML = "<div>" +
                            "This is some content" +
                           "</div>";  And that is document I am printing, where/how to put @page {margin: 0cm} ?